# Logging a route's entire URL string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm [having trouble](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/issues/22) with Facebook's callback into my website when I log in via Facebook.

I'm trying to log the full redirect URL from the controller method, but so far have only got as far as the URL parameters:

```
ob_start();
var_dump(Input::all());
$err = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
Log::error($err);
```

Can I log the raw URL string?

Comment: Have you tried to use variables from $_SERVER, like $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input` is a facade which uses symfony2 `HttpFoundation` component and almost all methods of `HttpFoundation\Request` are implemented. You can use `getRequestUri()` method.

```
Input::getRequestUri()
```

Or if you need the scheme and host :

```
Input::getSchemeAndHttpHost() . Input::getRequestUri()
```

Or even

```
URL::full()
```